# Kibana dashboard not loading using Apache2 ProxyPass

Tags: elasticsearch, apache2, kibana

I'm trying to setup kibana on a server, all seems fine and `curl -I my_server_address/kibana` returns a 200 (when doing the curl request remotely/from another machine). However, when I try to load that same url in a browser, nothing happens. My browser console tells me the following:

> Content Security Policy: Directive ‘child-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘worker-src’ to control workers, or directive ‘frame-src’ to control frames respectively.
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). kibana:372:1
>
> The script from “http://my_server_address/kibana/bundles/app/kibana/bootstrap.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“application/json”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
>   kibana
>
> Loading failed for the  with source “http://my_server_address/kibana/bundles/app/kibana/bootstrap.js”.

Of which the 1st, 3rd and 4th line are warnings, the 2nd ('settings blocked the loading of a resource...') is an error. I've also set this up on another machine and testing/accessing the Kibana GUI locally works, even though I get this error (second line), leading me to believe that perhaps it's not critical.

On the server, I've setup a proxypass with apache, the relevant lines in my sites-available/000-default.conf are:

```
ProxyPass /kibana http://localhost:5601/app/kibana
ProxyPassReverse /kibana http://localhost:5601/app/kibana
```

The only things I changed in my kibana.yaml file are:

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.basePath: "/kibana"
```

I've left the rest at its default. I suspect it has something to do with the redirecting/routing of apache2, causing the GUI to look for files in the wrong place, because the curl requests work fine.

Would be grateful for any thoughts or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Made a mistake in my apache confs, relevant lines from above should be:

```
ProxyPass /kibana http://localhost:5601
ProxyPassReverse /kibana http://localhost:5601
```

i.e. without /app/kibana